# Extract Characters on japanese PDF File in Python using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am implementing a to program to extract text from a PDF file. The PDF file composes of English words and Japanese Characters. I use PyPDF2, this is what i've tried

Example:

> japanese.pdf

```
Japan History
日本の歴史
```

> main.py

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('japanese.pdf','rb')   

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
num=pdfReader.numPages

for a in range(0, num):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(a)         
    text=pageObj.extractText().encode('utf-8')
    print(text)
```

> Result

```
b'Japan \nHistory\n\n\n\n'
```

How can i remove this \n and display this Japanese Characters

Answer (score 0):

Update your PyPDF2 version:

```
pip install PyPDF2 --upgrade
```

As of December 2022 the most recent version is `PyPDF2==2.12.1`. It supports all kinds of alphabets; I would be surprised if Japanese had issues. However, without an example document it's hard to tell. I don't speak/read Japanese.